# Deploy Rails program to Heroku under Fedora 15

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, fedora

```
[root@chris-notebook helloworld]# heroku create helloworld --stack cedar
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.8.0/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.8.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:17:in `block in load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.8.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:16:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.8.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:16:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.8.0/bin/heroku:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

When I try to create that, every time I got same error.
What should I do? I saw similar problems but under Ubuntu. They solve it by going some place ...src/ruby../ext/readline and then execute

```
ruby extconf.rb
make
make install
```

but I don't see that folder in file system. Why is it all so difficult?

### Update

Solved by installing next packages

```
readline-devel.i686
readline-static.i686
```

And then making similar operations in the folder `ext/readline` that placed in downloaded sources of ruby.

Comment: Take the 'update' section, post it as an answer yourself, then accept your own answer. It's just easier to follow.